# Incrementing counter within for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, counter

I am having trouble properly incrementing a counter variable within a for loop.

I have a variable called `flag`, and I want to create a new variable called `num` based on the values in `flag`.

Input:

```
'flag'
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
```

Desired output:

```
'flag' 'num'
FALSE   1
TRUE    1
TRUE    1
TRUE    1
FALSE   2
TRUE    2
FALSE   3
TRUE    3
TRUE    3
```

The goal is to start the num counter at 1 and keep that counter at 1 until another `False` instance occurs in the `flag` column.  This would be continued until the end of the df.

My code:

```
def num(z):  
    i = 0
    for x in range (0,len(z)):
        if z['flg'] == False:
            return i + 1
        else:
            return i

df['num']=df.apply(num, axis=1)
```

I have tried incrementing the I counter in numerous places, but no luck...

Comment: `z['flg']` always returns the same thing. Your loop does not affect it.

Comment: Also, if you meant to index `z` using `x`, iterate over `z.keys()`, not its length. And you shouldn't be returning in the loop. you should be doing `i = i+1` and returning at the end of the loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
df['num'] = (~df['flag']).cumsum()
```

uses the fact that `False = 0`, `True == 1`

if `df['num']` is not a column of True and False values, but a column of strings, I suggest you change that, or change the test to `df['num'] = (df['flag'] == 'FALSE').cumsum()`

Comment: very nice solution ;)

Comment: Very simple solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code in a corrected matter, but the solution by Maarten Fabré is nicer:

```
def num(z):
    i = 0
    numcol = []
    for flag in z:
        if not flag:
            i += 1
        numcol.append(i)
    return numcol

df['num'] = num(df['flag'])
```

At first I wanted to do it with a generator, but I did not get it to work with the pandas dataframe.